# Projectile: show project open buffers when switching project

Tags: spacemacs, customize, projectile, prelude, helm-projectile

I have a very large project and generally I work on multiple related projects simultaneously. While switching project I have to type full name everytime (multiple similar named files under different directories) to open a buffer which was already opened earlier as helm-projectile-find-files doesn't show already opened buffers. 
  How do I make projectile-project-switch-action to display and filter both project open buffers and rest of the project matches.

When I was using spacemacs I remember having this kind of behavior. I use prelude now.

Eg: 
project p1 has pp1, pp2, pp3 ...
Project a1 has aa1, aa2, aa3...
Project x1 has xx1, xx2, xx3...

Now assume I have 2 windows win1 and win2.
In win1 I have pp1 opened and in win2 aa1 is opened
Now I switch to project x1 in win1 and open file xx1
Now after viewing the file I try to switch back to project p1 in win1. After selecting project from projectile-switch-project projectile list me with all the files of p1 - pp1, pp2, pp3... to select a file and open it.
Now since I have already opened pp1 earlier if I could see a list of open buffers along with project files I could save some time.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `helm-projectile-switch-to-buffer`?

Comment: How about a reference, or an explanation of how that answers the question? Otherwise, consider changing this to a comment.

Comment: that is what I use when I'm inside the project. It will show only open buffers. But it will not help me while switching the project.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you update the question w/ an example (e.g. project `P1` with files `foo`, `bar`, `baz`, project `P2` with files `foo`, `quux`, and so on?

Comment: Added an example.